# How to schedule a REST API call with SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have built a RESTFUL API for my webscraper and was wondering if there was a way to schedule API calls in SSIS? Something similar to cronjob scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an SSIS package with a Script Task inside for calling the API. Then you deploy the package. Then you create a Job in which you call the package and schedule it (daily/weekly/monthly/every x minutes etc)

Hope this helps.